# Test concurrent users with different browsing patterns

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

So using Jmeter today and whilst I know i can load test a website with concurrent users using threads, loops etc I was wondering if it is possible to setup a test where say 50 users access the website and then each of them browse the site in a different way?

Has anyone done this before or would jmeter not be the tool to use?
Looking for some suggestions or an idea how to do it in Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have at least the following simple possibility:[Random Order Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Order_Controller).

Implement set of navigation/browsing steps via separate samplers or group of samplers (grouped via e.g. [Simple Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) or [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) - if some steps should be always executed in defined sequence).
This will be "pool" of navigation steps.
Adding all these steps as child samplers to the Random Order Controller let you have different, per user, randomly generated sequence of navigation steps.
In this case you possible have to put your login/logout samplers (if any) out from Random Order Controller. As well you can e.g. use both scenarios with and without login/logout, etc.

```
Thread Group
    ...
    Login Sampler
    Random Order Controller
        Sampler A
        Sampler B
        ...
        Sampler X
    Logout Sampler
    ...
```

As well you can also additionally look onto

- [Random Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller)
- [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller): e.g. define in csv-file per-user navigation scenarios, read these scenarios during script execution and assign extracted actions to each thread;
- [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller).